# Draggable element inside other draggable element event hidden by parent

Tags: javascript, css, html

So, I have a div inside of a div and both are draggable.
When I attempt to drag the child, it only drags the parent.

It is as if the parent is masking the child.

I tried setting the useCapture to true in the child's event listener as this should force the child event to be called first. Then in the handleDragStart method I call stopPropogation() in hopes that it'll supersede the parent event. No dice...

(example code because it is required for jsfiddle links for some reason)

```
var parentPiece = document.createElement('div');
parentPiece.setAttribute('draggable', true);
parentPiece.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);

...

var childPiece = document.createElement('div');
childPiece.setAttribute('draggable', true);
childPiece.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, true);

...

function handleDragStart(e) {
    console.log(this.outerHTML);
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Here's my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BenSeawalker/d1zp9Lto/). I apologize for the mess, first time trying to do drag'n'drop at all.

You should be able to drag elements from the bottom onto the lines, and into the blue square. Elements in lines should be dragable into other lines. The problem is with the dragable elements placed into the blue squares, it drags the whole line instead of the child that was clicked on.

I'm probably missing something really stupid like a CSS rule. >_<

**I'm open to using any libraries to make this cleaner/more maintainable.**

Any help is much appreciated while I try to learn this.
Thanks!

Comment: Garret, You could play with opacity or visibility, so you can reduce the node HTML elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with dynamic html elements.
Event listeners will not stick to them unless they are already in the DOM.
To get around this I added a hidden element and whenever I create a dynamic element I first add it as a child to hidden. Then when I'm ready to use it I move it to where it needs to be. This feels kind of hacky, but it works.